# Masonry is not a function in Ember Cli

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js, ember-cli, jquery-masonry

How can i initiate a jQuery plugin in Ember-Cli?

I am trying to use [Masonry plugin](http://masonry.desandro.com/layout.html) and this is the logic i want to implement

```
var $grid = $('.grid').masonry({
  itemSelector: '.grid-item',
  percentPosition: true,
  columnWidth: '.grid-sizer'
});
// layout Isotope after each image loads
$grid.imagesLoaded().progress( function() {
  $grid.masonry();
});
```

I am trying to use the event hook called `didInsertElement`, but the jQuery plugin does not initiate.

Here my code

```
import Ember from 'ember';

var PhotographyController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    didInsertElement : function(){
      this._super();
      Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', this, this.afterRenderEvent);
    },

    afterRenderEvent : function(){
      var $grid = $('.grid').masonry({
        itemSelector: '.grid-item',
        percentPosition: true,
        columnWidth: '.grid-sizer'
      });
      // layout Isotope after each image loads
      $grid.imagesLoaded().progress( function() {
        $grid.masonry();
      });  
    }
});

export default PhotographyController;
```

The console error "Masonry is not a function"

[image]

How can i initiate the Plugin and implement this logic?

I am using Ember 1.3.11

Comment: Have you tried to put the afterRenderEvent function implementation as the last param for the Ember.run.scheduleOnce function instead of passing as argument?

Comment: you  mean       Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', this, function(){
        var $grid = $('.grid').masonry({
          itemSelector: '.grid-item',
          percentPosition: true,
          columnWidth: '.grid-sizer'
        });
        // layout Isotope after each image loads
        $grid.imagesLoaded().progress( function() {
          $grid.masonry();
        });
      });
    }, ? It does not work

Comment: Controllers don't have access to the DOM, so they don't have a `didInsertElement` hook method. Is the code on the post correct? It looks like something in a component.

Comment: Yes i create the component then like in answer but i still get the console error "Uncaught TypeError: this.$(...).masonry is not a function"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently someone has already done something around [Masonry as an ember addon](https://github.com/gmurphey/ember-masonry-grid).

To try and answer your question, first off you must check if the Masonry file is included in your application.
In `ember-cli-build.js` you should have something along the lines of:

```
app.import('bower_components/mansonry/dist/masonry.min.js');
```

Do notice that I made the path for that, you need to make sure the path is correct for your project. Here I'm assuming you would be using bower to manage dependencies. So you would need to have something like this in your `bower.json` file (and then run `bower install`).

```
"masonry": "~3.3.2",
```

If you want to use jQuery in an Ember component (which is what I think you need here). You should do the following:

```
//components/masonry-component.js
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  didInsertElement() {
   var $grid = this.$('.grid').masonry({
    itemSelector: '.grid-item',
    percentPosition: true,
    columnWidth: '.grid-sizer'
  });
   // layout Isotope after each image loads
   $grid.imagesLoaded().progress( function() {
     $grid.masonry();
   });  
  }
});
```

Notice the use of `this.$('.grid')` this means that your using a jquery selector which only starts searching for elements in the context of your component (so that you can have multiple components without interfering with each other).
And in your component template the div with `grid` class:

```
<div class='grid'>
  {{yield}}
</div>
```

And in your route template you would have:

```
{{masonry-component}}
```

Comment: These are exactly all the steps i have done, in my vendor.js in dist i can see it compiled, the only difference is that i am using   "masonry": "~4.0.0", i still see in the console Uncaught TypeError: this.$(...).masonry is not a function, i do not know what else i have to check, i try to sort it out and give you answer accepted though

Comment: I am still using brocfile.js, here my import app.import('bower_components/masonry/dist/masonry.pkgd.min.js');

Comment: I'd have to try out. Can you make a github repo to reproduce the situation?

Comment: yes sure https://github.com/Mannaio/Portfolio/tree/features/flickr-api, check my last commit there and you see the last change done like in your answer

Comment: Sorry, I tried running it but I keep getting:
`Cannot read property 'displayHost' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'displayHost' of undefined
    at /Users/useruser/code/Portfolio/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/tasks/server/express-server.js:179:70` .

Comment: it looks like this is the issue https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/3519, contact me in pvt if u want go further https://github.com/Mannaio. many thanks!

Comment: Then i have found and tried this https://github.com/pitchtarget/ember-cli-pt-masonry and it did the job with the same answer